# FBSDKInternalUtility Exception using FBSDK framework in objectiveC

Tags: ios

I'm using `FBSDKCoreKit` framework for custom login. I followed the documentation perfectly. I'm using `FBSDKLoginManager` for Login.I'm unable to find why this exception was coming  and getting exception as 
`[FBSDKInternalUtility JSONStringForObject:error:]:` unrecognized selector sent to class.please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {

    } else if (result.isCancelled)
    {

    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
        {
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {

                         NSLog(@"find result=%@",result);
                     }
                 }];
            }

        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the similar issue when using `FBSDKShareKit`.framework and [`FBSDKCoreKit.framework`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads).
For my case, `FBSDKCoreKit` I was using was a little bit older than `FBSDKShareKit`. So I replaced them with that from the same download of `FacebookSDK` and "unrecognized selector" was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -ObjC in BuildSettings >> Other Linker Flags may solve your issue.

Comment: thanq for reply .I have given this -ObjC already.I don't think so that this is my issue